# to automate (manual)R code for calculation of P values

Tags: r

I Am trying to automate the below R code in which I am calculating the p values. The data is in csv format(in excel). I have clicks and open number for each section and their version. If someone can help with applying any loop or something.

Data I have in .csv format:

```
Section Version A   Version B   Version C   Version D
Section 1   2967    3353             495    559
Section 2   4840    4522             285    266
Section 3   
Section 4   
Section 5   
Main emailbody                  
Total email                 
          


Version # Opens
A    18223
B    
C    
D
```

### approach 1- (assign data manually from the csv file):

````
S1_Click_A=2967 #(section 1, email A)
S1_Click_B=3353 #(section 1, email B)
S1_Click_C=495
S1_Click_D=559
S2_Click_A=4840
...
S5_Click_D=154
MainBody_Click_A=12408
...
MainBody_Click_D=260
TotalEmail_Click_A=13525
..
TotalEmail_Click_D=248`

#no. email opens
Open_A=18223
Open_B=18368
Open_C=18223
Open_D=18368


#to test % total click is the comparable across versions
#section 1 test 
S1ab <- prop.test(x = c(S1_Click_A,S1_Click_B), n = c(Open_A,Open_B))
...
S1cd <- prop.test(x = c(S1_Click_C,S1_Click_D), n = c(Open_C,Open_D))

#section 2 test
S2ab <- prop.test(x = c(S2_Click_A,S2_Click_B), n = c(Open_A,Open_B))
...
S2cd <- prop.test(x = c(S2_Click_C,S2_Click_D), n = c(Open_C,Open_D))

#similarly for section 3,4 and 5

#Main body test
MainBodyab <- prop.test(x = c(MainBody_Click_A,MainBody_Click_B), n = 
c(Open_A,Open_B))
MainBodyac <- prop.test(x = c(MainBody_Click_A,MainBody_Click_C), n = 
c(Open_A,Open_C))
...
MainBodycd <- prop.test(x = c(MainBody_Click_C,MainBody_Click_D), n = 
c(Open_C,Open_D))

#Total Email test
 TotalEmailab <- prop.test(x = c(TotalEmail_Click_A,TotalEmail_Click_B), n 
 =c(Open_A,Open_B))
 ```
 TotalEmailcd <- prop.test(x = c(TotalEmail_Click_C,TotalEmail_Click_D), n 
 = c(Open_C,Open_D))

#FINAL P VALUE
S1ab$p.value
S1ac$p.value
````

### approach 2

```
# no. email opens
open <- 
c(
Open_A=18223,
Open_B=18368,
Open_C=18223,
Open_D=18368
)

s1 <- c(
S1_Click_A=2967, #(section 1, email A)
S1_Click_B=3353, #(section 1, email B)
S1_Click_C=495,
S1_Click_D=559
)

open_comb <- combn(names(open), 2)
s1_comb <- combn(names(s1), 2)
res_names <-  combn(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 2)

# to test % total click is the comparable across versions`
# section 1 test`
result1 <- list()
for(k in 1:length(open)){
result1[[paste0("s1", res_names[1, k], res_names[2, k])]] <- prop.test(x = 
s1[s1_comb[,k]], n = open[open_comb[,k]])
}
result_section1 <- c (ress1$s1AB$p.value, ress1$s1AC$p.value, 
ress1$s1AD$p.value, ress1$s1BC$p.value, ress1$s1BD$p.value, 
ress1$s1CD$p.value)
result_section1
```

However this automated code provides P values only for the below combination: AB, AC, AD, BC and not for BD and CD.
Might be this is because length of open i.e only 4(please help how to resolve)

```
I expect:
1. I want to read the input data directly from the csv. I mean reading the 
   section 1 version A data i.e 2967 then assign the same to 
   S1_Click_A=2967 variable and similarly for others.
2. Fix the code to provides P values only for all combination: AB, AC, AD, BC,BD and CD.
```

dput(data)

```
structure(list(Section = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 7L), .Label = 
c("Main email body", "Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4", 
"Section 5", "Total email"), class = "factor"), Version.A = c(2967L, 4840L, 
2508L, 2093L, 1117L, 12408L, 13525L), Version.B = c(3353L, 4522L, 2250L, 
1333L, 925L, 11458L, 12383L), Version.C = c(495L, 285L, 228L, 209L, 186L, 
282L, 271L), Version.D = c(559L, 266L, 205L, 133L, 154L, 260L, 248L)), class 
= "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L ))
```

Comment: Could you post the literal contents of the .csv file? We'd need that if you want us to answer __1.__

Comment: Please don't use external links (links die), add the content to the question body. If it's very big, subset it.

Comment: updated the content @AkselA

Comment: Is that the literal content of your .csv file? I see no commas.

Comment: But you are using `read.csv()` to read it into R?

Comment: sorry in case of any confusion. I am updating the data manually into R to each variable. I want to assign values to each variable
for exa: 
S1_Click_A=2967,
S1_Click_B=3353,
S1_Click_C=495,
S1_Click_D=559 and simillarly for section2,3 and so on..

Comment: approach 2 is working fine now.
I just added section1 clicks in s1 and removed others.
Initially I was including all section clicks in s1 variable.
So now I have s1 <- all clicks for section 1
s2 <- all clicks for s2 and same for others

Comment: Why not read it in directly? Using something like [googlesheets](https://datascienceplus.com/how-to-use-googlesheets-to-connect-r-to-google-sheets/) you can even read it in directly, no download to disk required.

Comment: I think for this I need to give access to my account drive, which I cannot due to security reason. Imagine the data is in local disk and I have imported the same using read.csv()and  now if I want to assign the data values(1st row of section 1 cobintaion with their version) to each variable naming as above, can you help me with the R code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider reshaping your data from its original wide format to long. Then run `prop.test` by each *Section* and across all combinations of *Version*. Below builds a list of elements containing `prop.test` results (including but not limited to p-values) for all 6 combinations per 7 sections.

**Data**

```
txt <- '"Section" "Version A"   "Version B"   "Version C"   "Version D"
"Section 1"   2967    3353             495    559
"Section 2"   4840    4522             285    266
"Section 3"   2508    2250             228    205
"Section 4"   2093    1333             209    133
"Section 5"   1117    925              186    154
"Main emailbody"  12408   11458        282    260
"Total email" 13525   12383            271    248'

df <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

open_df <- data.frame(Version = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                      Open = c(18223, 18368, 18223, 18368))
```

**`reshape` + `by`**

```
# RESHAPE WIDE TO LONG
rdf <- reshape(df, idvar = "Section", varying = list(names(df)[-1]),
               times = names(df)[-1], v.names = "Value", timevar = "Version",
               new.row.names = 1:1E5, direction = "long")

rdf$Version  <- gsub("Version.", "", rdf$Version)

# SUBSET BY SECTION AND RUN prop.test ON ALL COMBS
prop_test_list <- by(rdf, rdf$Section, function(sub) {
    pairs <- combn(sub$Version, 2, simplify = FALSE)

    sapply(pairs, function(item) 
             prop.test(x = sub$Value[sub$Version %in% item], 
                       n = open_df$Open[open_df$Version %in% item])
          )
})
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/XUH15672)

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks a lot @Parfait it working what I was exactly looking for. Can you just let me know how I can only extract p values from prop_test_list$`Section 1`. A
As you are the one who understand the problem exactly, so I would like to ask one more question; consider we have open for different version w.r.t their different section. Similar to the format we have clicks data here.
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! If you only want p-values, inside `sapply` , call the element on prop test: `prop.test(...)$p.value`.

Comment: Thanks Parfait! I got the p values, however I am getting the values in list (I need to copy paste the numbers one by one manually) for which I did this: result <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(prop_test_list), nrow=length(prop_test_list), byrow=T))
result. Can you help me how I can get the same row and col names as Total clicks dataframe.